# Need help figuring out error "Code was invalid or expired"

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

I'm using version 6.0.10.0 of the Facebook.dll from the SDK.  We are beta testing our application and one of my users cannot login.  The user is on an iMac using Chrome.

I am using the server side flow,  not using the Facebook Javascript SDK at all.

Here is a snippet of server side code i'm using to retrieve data from Facebook...  (This code came directly from a sample somewhere, so credit is due to that author :-) )

```
var fbClient = new FacebookClient();
        var oauthResult = fbClient.ParseOAuthCallbackUrl(pRequestUri);

        string accessToken = null;
        DateTime expires = DateTime.Now;       

        // Exchange the code for an access token
        dynamic result = fbClient.Get("/oauth/access_token", new
        {
            client_id = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FacebookAppId"],
            redirect_uri = pRedirectUri.AbsoluteUri,
            client_secret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FacebookAppSecret"],
            code = oauthResult.Code,
        });
        accessToken = result.access_token;
        expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(Convert.ToDouble(result.expires));

        // Get the user's profile information
        dynamic me = fbClient.Get("/me",
        new
        {
            fields = "first_name,last_name,email,name",
            access_token = accessToken
        });

        // Read the Facebook user values
        string sfacebookId = me.id;
        string firstName = me.first_name;
        string lastName = me.last_name;
        string email = me.email;
```

Here is the detail of the exception from my logs.

```
(OAuthException - #100) Code was invalid or expired. 

This may be because the user logged out or may be due to a system error.

source="Facebook" detail="Facebook.FacebookOAuthException: (OAuthException - #100) Code  was invalid or expired. This may be because the user logged out or may be due to a system error.

Stack Trace:

at Facebook.FacebookClient.ProcessResponse(HttpHelper httpHelper, String responseString, Type resultType, Boolean containsEtag, IList`1 batchEtags)

at Facebook.FacebookClient.Api(HttpMethod httpMethod, String path, Object parameters, Type resultType)   

at Facebook.FacebookClient.Get(String path, Object parameters)
```

The query string returned from Facebook includes the parameter code and it has a value.

It is easy to see from the stack trace that the first .Get() method call in my code ends up calling the .ProcessResponse() method which throws the error.

Unfortunately, everywhere I search talks about what to do with an expired access token.

In my case, I have not even retrieved an access token yet,  it is my code that is expired or invalid. How can I request a new code?

Thanks,

Comment: try using TryParseOAuthCallbackUrl and also check if result.IsSuccess is true and !string.IsNullOrEmpty(result.Code)

Comment: @prabir:  Adding those checks will make sure the code is valid, but I still want the users access_token.    How can I go about getting their access_token in this scenario?   What your telling me will keep the user from logging in.

Comment: are you sure there is a code in querystring?

Comment: @prabir:  Thanks for the follow up question.  Yes i'm sure their is a code in the querystring.     The log specifies the querystring as  lat=39.2313943&long=-94.5828166&code=AQCM_.....   (removed extra characters from the code).    the lat and long are parameters from my application.

Comment: when fb redirects to ur page you never get lat long, those should be part of state. ur doing something wrong. checkout https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk/facebook-aspnet-sample

Comment: @prabir:  I pass lat / long from my own application.  I send this in the querystring and FB returns it.    The server authentication flow works for all users except this one.     Any other thoughts?  If not I will have to move to the Javascript SDK from FB.

Comment: @RDotLee, are you certain that the redirect_uri passed in is *exactly* identical to the one sent to the authorize endpoints? That is a mandatory criteria for exchanging the code for the access token.

Comment: @SeanKinsey,  thanks for the response.  I'm pretty sure it was identical as it worked for all beta testers except one.  I'm not sure why it would have been different for one user.   

The client side flow seems to work well for me, so I will stick with it.  Thanks again for your response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could never get the server side flow working for all my users, so I went ahead and switched to the FB Javascript SDK and it is working for me now.